# How does the page style myheadings work?

Tags: header-footer

I do not understand how to use the basic heading. Why does the following not create left and right headers? (`\markright` gives the same problem.)

```
\documentclass[oneside]{article}
\pagestyle{myheadings}
\markboth{left}{right}

\begin{document}
.
\end{document}
```

Produces:

[image]

I am using Kopka and Daly's book, 4th ed. page 46.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\markboth` doesn't set the left and right header parts of the current page but the *marks* for the headers of even/left and odd/right pages. Marks are some kind of internal labels that are stored for a page that can be accessed later when the page is build.

Your document starts with an odd page, so you get "right" in the header. Furthermore, with the `oneside` option enabled you also get "right" on all subsequent pages as they are all treated as right pages. You can see the effect if you change the class option to `twoside` and add some new empty pages. Now your header toggles between "right" and "left" in the header.

What's going on internally? If you select the `myheadings` page style, LaTeX calls a macro `\ps@myheadings` which does all the relevant setting. Among others we see

```
\def \@evenhead {\thepage \hfil \slshape \leftmark }
\def \@oddhead {{\slshape \rightmark }\hfil \thepage }
```

where `\@oddhead` is the macro called when headers of odd/right pages are being set. The format is exactly that what you see in the output of your example document. `\rightmark` here is the text (implicitly) set by `\markboth`.

Note that a call of `\markboth` doesn't set the text of the `\leftmark` and `\rightmark` marks directly but uses TeX's mark system internally. So LaTeX's `leftmark` basically corresponds to TeX's `\botmark` (the last mark on a page), and `\rightmark` to `\firstmark` (the first mark on a page). So you might expect a second call of `\markboth` to change the first page's header to the new right text, but instead the text from the first call, i.e. the value of `\firstmark`, is used.

Also have a look at Section 9 of the [documentation of the `fancyhdr` package](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.pdf) which explains the marks system in more detail. I strongly recommend changing page styles via this package instead of doing it manually.

Comment: Once again, the package wins.